# using perl to build commandline args in gdb in Cygwin

Tags: perl, gdb, cygwin

I've used perl commands before to build commandline arguments in gdb (example: run `perl -e 'print "A"x20'`), but my Cygwin install doesn't parse the commands, it treats them as literal strings (argv[1] = "perl", argv[2] = "-e", etc...)

Is this some type of Cygwin environment that needs to be set up, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Cygwin specifically, but in a Windows Command you have to double quote the perl expression and struggle inside the one-liner if you need double quotes (you can use qq for example).  So on my WinXP machine this:

```
perl -e "print 'A'x20"
```

prints 20 A's.

Comment: nope. in a basic program which does a printf of argv[1], the following occurred:  

`    $ gdb test Reading symbols from /home/user/test...done. 
(gdb) run perl -e "print 'a'x20"; 
Starting program: /home/user/test perl -e "print 'a'x20"; 
[New Thread 3664.0x146c] 
[New Thread 3664.0x2110] 
perl 
[Inferior 1 (process 3664) exited normally] 
(gdb) $ 
`
As you can see, it's treating perl like it is a string